# What's the correct flow type for `Comp` in this React HOC?

Tags: react-native, flowtype

```
export default Comp => ({ children, ...props }: { children?: Node }) => (
  <KeyboardAvoidingWrapper
    keyboardVerticalOffset={-getBottomSpace() / 2}
    behavior="padding"
    enabled
  >
    <Comp {...props}>{children}</Comp>
  </KeyboardAvoidingWrapper>
);
```

this is the error code flow generates:
*Missing type annotation for 'Comp'.Flow(InferError)*

Edit: 
FlowVersion: 0.78.0
RNVersion: 0.57

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From flow 0.89.0, the type you want to use for wrapped components in HOCs is [`React.AbstractComponent`](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-abstractcomponent).

This type takes two type parameters, the `Config` and the `Instance`. `Instance` can usually be safely ignored, and `Config`, while technically containing both the `Props` type *and* `DefaultProps`, is effectively just used as the `Props` type. So, we can type basically any react component (class, function, what have you) as `React.AbstractComponent<Props>`.

```
// @flow
import * as React from 'react';

export default <Props: { children: React.Node }>(
  Comp: React.AbstractComponent<Props>,
) => ({ children, ...props }: Props) => (
  //...
);
```

Note that we're adding a [bound](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/#toc-generic-types-act-as-bounds) to the `Props` [generic](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/) to tell flow that `Props` will always contain the property `children` of type `React.Node`, otherwise when we try to extract `children` from our `Props`, flow won't know that it exists.

Buuuut, since you're working with react-native in an older flow version, you'll need to use `React.ComponentType` which is slightly less abstract (it doesn't do the `Instance` stuff briefly mentioned earlier). [Here's](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gFSgCGAzqAEoCmRAxnpFrKqAORbV0sDciilAHplygAJpUhEArtDwAeAAqN0JAFygA3qBoALZNBHsAdmqq0cAOgBysMaAC+APgAUiUKADCTdCY4XPGWENKQxwAFQBPdEoFJRIHABpEAEpQAF4HUCdNHT0DYPjQcyL0WPs1RVhlFPTM11BZf3QNIvMSypJHdRz9IztZYEaHZK4gA) an example.

Comment: what if my flow version is 0.78.0?, since my react-native is 0.57, I can't use 0.89.0, or could I?

Comment: Ah, then you want [`React.ComponentType`](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gFSgCGAzqAEoCmRAxnpFrKqAORbV0sDciilAHplygAJpUhEArtDwAeAAqN0JAFygA3qBoALZNBHsAdmqq0cAOgBysMaAC+APgAUiUKADCTdCY4XPGWENKQxwAFQBPdEoFJRIHABpEAEpQAF4HUCdNHT0DYPjQcyL0WPs1RVhlFPTM11BZf3QNIvMSypJHdRz9IztZYEaHZK4gA). It's slightly less abstract but should suit your purpose. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: "I can't use 0.89.0, or could I?"

I would answer this question, but I don't really know the react-native ecosystem :)

Comment: tnx lyle, helpful stuff

Answer (score 0):

May be because you are using `<Comp />` before you defined it?
export default Comp, exporting a component function, and you calling a component inside it, which is maybe undefined. 
May be try this first, see the error gone or not?

```
export default Comp => ({ children, ...props }: { children?: Node }) => (
  <KeyboardAvoidingWrapper
    keyboardVerticalOffset={-getBottomSpace() / 2}
    behavior="padding"
    enabled
  >
    <Text {...props}>{children}</Text>
  </KeyboardAvoidingWrapper>
);
```